# C++ ; Write a program that reads in ten whole numbers

Tags: c++

Write a program that reads in ten whole numbers and that outputs the sum of all the numbers greater than zero, the sum of all the numbers less than zero (which will be a negative or zero), and the sum of all the numbers, whether positive, negative, or zero. The user enters the ten numbers just once each and the user can enter them in any order. Your program should not ask the user to enter the positive numbers and the negative numbers separately. Now modify this program so that it outputs the sum of all positive numbers, the average of all positive numbers, the sum of all non-positive numbers, the average of all non-positive numbers, the sum of all positive and non-positive numbers, and the average of all numbers entered.

This is what I have so far...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     int number, negative_sum=0, positive_sum=0, sum=0, average_neg, 
         average_pos, average;
     int count=0, positiveCount=0, negativeCount=0; 

     cout << "Please Input 10 whole numbers(Each number should be separated by space or Enter)\n";
     for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         cin >> number;

     if (number >= 0 )
     {
         positive_sum += number;
         positiveCount++;  
     } 
     else     
     {
         negative_sum += number ; 
         negativeCount++; 
     } 
     }

     average_pos = positive_sum / positiveCount;
     average_neg = negative_sum / negativeCount; 
     sum = positive_sum + negative_sum;
     average = sum / count; 

     cout << "The Total sum of Positive Numbers is " << positive_sum << " and the average of \nThe postive numbers entered is ";
     cout << average_pos<< endl; 
     cout << "The Total sum of Negative Numbers is " << negative_sum << " and the average of \nThe negative numbers entered is ";
     cout << average_neg << endl; 
     cout << "The Total sum of numbers entered is " << sum << " and its average is "<< average << endl;

     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

Basically it is just printing the "Please Input 10 whole numbers(Each number should be separated by space or Enter)\n" part multiple times after I entered numbers.

Comment: Learn about arrays.  Enough said...

Comment: The for loop should be closed after the if/else part - or is this a typo?

Comment: @MikeMB wasn't typo. fixed it^ but now it just "stopped working"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Should I include it even if my teacher hasn't taught it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Considering this is a C++ question, there are much better things to learn about than arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that a zero divided by zero division occurs in the lines `average_pos = positive_sum / positiveCount;` `average = sum / count;` and `average_neg = negative_sum / negativeCount;`. In order to avoid this you can add `if` conditions which perform the division only when  `positiveCount`, `negativeCount` and `count` `are  greater than 0`

Also, in your code you are dividing `sum` by `count` in the line `average = sum / count;` but no where in your code is `count` being incremented.
Your `for` loop was also ended prematurely.

**The Correct Modified Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{

int number, negative_sum=0, positive_sum=0, sum=0, average_neg=0, 
average_pos=0, average=0;
int count=0, positiveCount=0, negativeCount=0; 
cout << "Please Input 10 whole numbers(Each number should be separated by space or       Enter)\n";

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {

 //cout<<"i is"<<i<<endl;
cin >> number;

if (number >= 0 )
 {
     positive_sum += number;
     positiveCount++;  count++;
 } 

 else     
 {
     negative_sum += number ; 
     negativeCount++; count++;
 }  
 }
if(positiveCount>0)
{
 average_pos = positive_sum / positiveCount;
}

if(negativeCount>0)
{ 
average_neg = negative_sum / negativeCount; 
}

sum = positive_sum + negative_sum;

if(count>0)
{
  average = sum / count;
} 

 cout<<average_pos;
 cout << "The Total sum of Positive Numbers is " << positive_sum << " and the average of   \nThe postive numbers entered is ";
 cout << average_pos<< endl; 
 cout << "The Total sum of Negative Numbers is " << negative_sum << " and the average of  \nThe negative numbers entered is ";
 cout << average_neg << endl; 
 cout << "The Total sum of numbers entered is " << sum << " and its average is "<< average << endl;

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I get a number for "average of negative" after inputing all positive

"The Total sum of Negative Numbers is 0 and the average of
negative numbers entered is 8139408"

Comment: Recheck if you have used the exact code as posted above, because for me it says 'The total sum of Negative numbers is 0 and the average of negative number is 0' when I enter all positive numbers

Comment: Cool Thanks again. Had to set initial values to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int number, negative_sum=0, positive_sum=0, sum=0, average_neg = 0,
average_pos = 0, average = 0;
int count=0, positiveCount=0, negativeCount=0;
cout << "Please Input 10 whole numbers(Each number should be separated by space or Enter)\n";
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
cin >> number;
if (number >= 0 )
{
positive_sum += number;
positiveCount++;
}
else
{
negative_sum += number ;
negativeCount++;
}
}
average_pos = positive_sum / positiveCount;
average_neg = negative_sum / negativeCount;
sum = positive_sum + negative_sum;
average = sum / count;
cout << "The Total sum of Positive Numbers is " << positive_sum << " and the average of \nThe postive numbers entered is ";
cout << average_pos<< endl;
cout << "The Total sum of Negative Numbers is " << negative_sum << " and the average of \nThe negative numbers entered is ";
cout << average_neg << endl;
cout << "The Total sum of numbers entered is " << sum << " and its average is "<< average << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the accepted answer to this question, so that it is useful to other users with similar questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     int number, negative_sum=0, positive_sum=0, sum=0, average_neg = 0, 
         average_pos = 0, average = 0;
     int count=0, positiveCount=0, negativeCount=0; 

 cout << "Please Input 10 whole numbers(Each number should be separated by space or Enter)\n";
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     cin >> number;
     if (number >= 0 )
     {
         positive_sum += number;
         positiveCount++;  
     } 
     else     
     {
         negative_sum += number ; 
         negativeCount++; 
     } 
  }
  average_pos = positive_sum / positiveCount;
  average_neg = negative_sum / negativeCount; 
  sum = positive_sum + negative_sum;
  average = sum / count; 

 cout << "The Total sum of Positive Numbers is " << positive_sum << " and the average of \nThe postive numbers entered is ";
 cout << average_pos<< endl; 
 cout << "The Total sum of Negative Numbers is " << negative_sum << " and the average of \nThe negative numbers entered is ";
 cout << average_neg << endl; 
 cout << "The Total sum of numbers entered is " << sum << " and its average is "<< average << endl;

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps ... :)